# getting a java.lang.IllegalAccessError in a Maven Spring project

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, pom.xml

I'm doing my first maven spring Rest project which includes an embedded tomcat service and some MongoDb queries. I'm very new to both Maven and Spring, and can't seem to understand this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/List; from class org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:920)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at com.cave.spring.firstSpring.Application.main(Application.java:12)
```

This is the exception I'm getting. I'm trying to start an embedded tomcat service, but I keep getting errors. I think there are some incompatabilities in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
     <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
     <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.cave.spring.firstSpring.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/firstSpring</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3.2</version> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: I eventually managed to get this resolved. 
I think there was some dependency issues. I stripped down the pom and imported the dependencies anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get this resolved. I think there was some dependency issues. I stripped down the pom and imported the dependencies anew

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `<version>` attributes, for the dependencies that are defined in the spring boot parent pom (like you did for `spring-boot-starter-web`).

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <!-- i dont know if this is defined in the parent pom -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- i dont know if this is defined in the parent pom -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>          
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```